# How to change every tag with display:flex

Tags: javascript

I have a page that uses display: flex quite often, that does not render correctly for the RPA software I am trying to use. I am trying to write a small javascript snippet that changes the display to something that my RPA software can actually render. I know it won't look good, but I just need it to show something instead of nothing.

Here is the js that I would expect to work:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     var curr_tag = all[i];
     console.log(getComputedStyle(curr_tag).display);
     if (getComputedStyle(curr_tag).display == "flex") {
       all[i].setAttribute("style", "height: 200px;");
     };
};
```

I would expect the console to have at least a few "flex" results, because using the devtools I can see that there are elements with "flex" as their computed style.

The results I actually get, are "display, inline, etc" but no flex for some reason.

Side note: I cannot use Jquery